# Show Blue scree without Image

Tags: sapui5, carousel

The following code is not working on my SAP WebIDE. When I run the `index.html` it shows the blank page.

Code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <!--Use the xml view from folder view -->
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>OpenSAP - Developing Web Apps with SAPUI5</title>

        <script
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
              "opensap.myapp": "./"
            }'>
        </script>

    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.xmlview({
                viewName: "opensap.myapp.week1u21.view.App"
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>
   </head>
   <body class="sapUiBody" id="content"></body>
</html>
```

App.view.xml

```
<mvc:View
  displayBlock="true"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <Carousel>
    <Pages>
      <Image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/GEO_Globe_10.jpg" 
    height="400px"/>
      <Image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Globe_Atlantic.svg" 
    height="400px"/>
    </Pages>
</Carousel>
```

My Folder path in SAP WebIDE is as under. Please review below screen link.

[image: Screen]

Please help me to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you, aggregation for the `Carousel` control is `pages`

```
<Carousel class="sapUiContentPadding" loop="true">
    <pages> <!-- this should in small letters -->
        <Image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/GEO_Globe_10.jpg" height="400px"/> 
        <Image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Globe_Atlantic.svg" height="400px"/>        
    </pages>
</Carousel>
```

Note: Kindly see browser console for JavaScript errors.